# Are any interesting classes of polynomial sequences besides Sheffer sequences groups under umbral composition?

Tags: gr.group-theory, polynomials, umbral-calculus

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3758097/are-any-interesting-classes-of-polynomial-sequences-besides-sheffer-sequences-gr) on math.stackexchange.com has 35 views, three up-votes, and not a word from anybody, so I'm posting it here.

Let us understand the term **polynomial sequence** to mean a sequence $(p_n(x))_{n=0}^\infty$ in which the degree of $p_n(x)$ is $n.$

The **umbral composition** $((p_n\circ q)(x))_{n=0}^\infty$ (not $((p_n\circ q_n)(x))_{n=0}^\infty$) of two polynomial sequences $(p_n(x))_{n=0}^\infty$ and $(q_n(x))_{n=0}^\infty,$ where for every $n$ we have $p_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n p_{nk} x^k,$ is given by
$$
(p_n\circ q)(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n p_{nk} q_k(x).
$$

An **Appell sequence** is a polynomial sequence $(p_n(x))_{n=0}^\infty$ for which $p\,'_n(x) = np_{n-1}(x)$ for $n\ge1.$

A **sequence of binomial type** is a polynomial sequence $(p_n(x))_{n=0}^\infty$ for which $$ p_n(x+y) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom n k p_k(x) p_{n-k}(y) $$
for $n\ge0.$

A **Sheffer sequence** is a polynomial sequence $(p_n(x))_{n=0}^\infty$ for which the linear operator from polynomials to polynomials that is characterized by $p_n(x) \mapsto np_{n-1}(x)$ is shift-equivariant. A shift is a mapping from polynomials to polynomials that has the form $p(x) \mapsto p(x+c),$ where every term gets expanded via the binomial theorem.

At least since around 1970, it has been known that

- Every Appell sequence and every sequence of binomial type is a Sheffer sequence.
- The set of Sheffer sequences is a group under umbral composition.
- The set of Appell sequences is an abelian group under umbral composition.
- The set of sequences of binomial type is a non-abelian group under umbral composition.
- The group of Sheffer sequences is a semi-direct product of those other two groups.
- For every sequence $a_0, a_1, a_2, \ldots$ of scalars there is a unique Appel sequence $(p_n(x))_{n=0}^\infty$ for which $p_n(0) = a_n$ for $n\ge0.$
- For every sequence $c_1, c_2, c_3, \ldots$ of scalars there is a unique sequence $(p_n(x))_{n=0}^\infty$ of binomial type for which $p\,'_n(0) = c_n$ for $n\ge1.$ This can be proved by induction on $n.$ (And in every case $p_0(0)=1$ and $p_n(0)=0$ for $n\ge 1.$)

**So my question is** whether Sheffer sequences exhaust the list of interesting classes of polynomial sequences that are groups under this operation? Are there any others of interest?

Comment: Exercises 5.37(b,e) and 5.38 of *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol. 2, gives some examples of polynomial sequences of binomial type. Exercise 4.47(f) of *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol. 1, second ed., gives an especially interersting example.

Comment: Among well known Appell sequences are the Hermite polynomials and the Bernoulli polynomials. Among well known sequences of binomial type are the rising factorials and the falling factorials.

Comment: @RichardStanley : I just noticed that my posting was vulnerable to a misinterpretation, so I deleted a paragraph and moved it down here to the comments. The question at the bottom of the posting was intended to means _besides Sheffer sequences_ and subgroups of Sheffer sequences, are there other interesting examples.

Comment: You must restrict to $A_0(x)=a_0= 1$ to obtain a canonical Appell seq with the raising op $R A_n(x) = A_{n+1}(x)$. Compare https://oeis.org/A238385 with https://oeis.org/A238363. // Since umbral composition is related to matrix multiplication of a pair of inverse lower triangular matrices, the question is tantamount to asking if Sheffer sequences are in bijection with that class of matrices, I believe.

Comment: Then the answer would be that I can have an invertible LT matrix whose first element is not unity as it must be for a Sheffer sequence. For Appell and binomial sequences the main diagonal must be all ones. For Appells, the first column is $a_n$. For binomials, the first column must have all zeros but for the initial 1. The general Sheffer seq is a sem-direct product of these two. Maybe proceed in this direction, contrasting invertible pairs of LTMs with the restrictions on those for Sheffers. E.g. maybe, https://oeis.org/A008275 vs. https://oeis.org/A048994, a simple case.

Comment: @TomCopeland : For sequences of binomial type the main diagonal is not generally all 1s, but rather all $n$th powers of one scalar, where $n$ is the degree.

Comment: Ahh, right. $a_{n,n}=(h'(0))^n$, where $e^{xh(t)}=e^{tp.(x)}$. Been working with a restricted subgroup too long. The relation to general invertible LTM holds. See Zemei's paper.

Comment: Loeb, on the second (unnumbered) page of "The World of Generating Functions and Umbral Calculus" discusses the analogy between the algebra of triangular matrices of the coefficients of Sheffer sequences and that of incidence algebras with the IA being the more general construct. Umbral composition of Sheffer polynomials, as I noted above, is equivalent to matrix multiplication of lower triangular matrices, and, in analogy, Loeb speaks of the closure of an incidence algebra on a poset.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another equivalent characterization of Sheffer sequences is that they fit into a generating function of the form
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{p_n(x)}{n!}t^n=f(t)e^{xg(t)}.$$
Most of the results on Sheffer sequences apply to a more general setting where we work with a function $\Psi(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}x^n/c_n$ and define $\Psi$-Sheffer sequences as those which satisfy a generating function of the form
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{p_n(x)}{c_n}t^n=f(t)\Psi(xg(t)).$$
These $\Psi$-Sheffer sequences also form a group under Umbral composition and this group is also a semidirect product of its $\Psi$-Appell subgroup and $\Psi$-binomial type subgroup. It should be noted that abstractly these groups are all isomorphic no matter the choice of $\Psi$: Let $A$ be the group of invertible power series $\mathbb C[[x]]^{\times}$ under multiplication and let $B$ be the (nonabelian) group $x\mathbb C[[x]]^{\times}$ under composition. We can let $B$ act on $A$ by composition and the result is that the group of $\Psi$-Sheffer sequences is isomorphic to the semidirect product of $B$ and $A$.

The details and proofs can be found in Steven Roman's papers "The Theory of the Umbral Calculus I-III", where he gives lots of examples of families of special polynomials that can be treated by this new umbral setting: Chebyshev, Jacobi, Gegenbauer etc. For a treatment that is a more modern you can see S. Zemel ["Generalized Riordan groups and operators on polynomials"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379516000240#se0060).

Comment: A 2020 revision of Zemel's paper is at https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.03100.